# Add controls to recent form after submit Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have input with phone number, if the phone number is valid then the form will open more 5 inputs to full.

```
this.contactUsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     contact_number: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.globalService.pattern)]), {disabled: true}],        
});
```

How can I add more contorls without affect on my contact_number value. I just want to add more controls like this:

```
this.contactUsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       contact_number: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.globalService.pattern)]), {disabled: true}],
       verification_code: ['', Validators.required]
       firstname: ['', Validators.required]
       lastname: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

I tried to this after contact_number success:

```
this.contactUsForm.addControl('verification_code',  new FormControl('', Validators.required));
```

But I had an error **ERROR TypeError: v is not a function**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bf4q3q

Comment: can you provide a reproduction on stackblitz?

Comment: share us your full code here, or create a stackblitz

Comment: check edit please

Comment: @YazanMehrez, just a quick note: 
You've forgot to add commas after "verification_code: ['', Validators.required]" and other stuff you are trying to add. Could you pls add commas after those items and check if the issue still persists?

Comment: @JustShadow Thank you for your note, check my stackbiltz above please.

Comment: If I add the `this.contactUsForm.addControl('verification_code',  new FormControl('', Validators.required));` in the `else` in your stackblitz, I don't see any errors and the form seems to be working? [edited stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxpxdt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for comments. The error appeared because I was doing this

```
this.contactUsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            contact_number: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.globalService.pattern)]), {disabled: true}],
        });
```

It worked after removing `{disabled: true}`